# Azure function 2.x ILogger is not competible with .net core ILogger?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, .net-core, azure-functions

I have been trying to refer a .net core library project into my Azure function project to call one of the process defined in a .net core class library.

The .net core library project uses ILogger.

However, whenever I try to run a function I get the following error:

> [29/11/2019 1:08:35 AM] The 'Function1' function is in error:
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Function1'.
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Cannot bind parameter 'log' to type
>   ILogger`1. Make sure the parameter Type is supported by the binding.
>   If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus,
>   Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the
>   extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(),
>   builder.AddServiceBus(),

This is my code:

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
            // string templateFile = Path.Combine(context.FunctionAppDirectory, "Data", "HelloHttpOutputTemplate.txt");
            Startup.Main(null).Wait();
        }
```

I also confirmed that my .net core project as well as function project are referring a same version of ILogger:

> 'microsoft.extensions.logging.abstractions\3.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0'

If I remove a .net core library project reference from within function project then it works.

My function CS Project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="..\Accounts.Console\appsettings.json" Link="appsettings.json" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.28" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Accounts.Console\Accounts.Console.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

My .net core Library project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <StartupObject></StartupObject>
    <ApplicationIcon />
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="librdkafka.redist" Version="1.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" Version="3.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>


  </Project>
```

Comment: If you're developing locally, can you show your .csproj file? It makes no sense to show your function code for this error.

Comment: @BowmanZhu Thanks I have just updated my question.

Comment: Hi, I have update my answer.

Comment: @BowmanZhu Thank you the compilation, and registration of a azure function by runtime problem was solved by what you'd suggested. However, I will not use the same because it caused me other issues in the app where I was using logger and method was not found in lower version. 

The permanent solution I found is to update to function v3, which is in preview at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**

Have use `.net core 3.0` now.

[image]

But still meet the same error:

[image]

This is my `.csproj` file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="librdkafka.redist" Version="1.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.28" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**Solution:**

Downgrading the version of `Microsoft.Extensions.Http`, `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console`, `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug` and `Microsoft.Extensions.Options` from `3.0.0` to `2.2.0`. Then error will be solved.

[image]

---

***Original Answer:***

I have reproduce your error:

[image]

**Cause:**

Assembly conflict. The key is your last four assembly references.

**Solution:**

Change them to `2.2.0`. Things works fine on my side. Please have a try on your side and let me know if you have difficulties.

**My `.csproj` file:**

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="librdkafka.redist" Version="1.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.29" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your efforts. So I should basically move to 2x net core, while I want to use 3x.

Comment: @codebased Did you try? I have something to do now and I will try version 3.0 later.

Comment: Yes if you want to use 3x you should use the 3x preview https://dev.to/azure/develop-azure-functions-using-net-core-3-0-gcm

Comment: Tried that path too but it could not find runtime even when I ran npm as suggested. I cannot find visual studio with preview template in VS 2019 16.3.10 version.